# What does h is not defined mean?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, storybook, figma

I've used `vue create` to setup a new Vue project, and have installed Storybook - all working correctly.

I have then installed [`storybook-addon-designs`](https://github.com/pocka/storybook-addon-designs) and followed the readme on adding to my story,  but it gives me the following error in my console: `h is not defined`.

Here's my files:

`stories/2-PageTitle.stories.js`:

```
import { withDesign } from 'storybook-addon-designs'
import {Button} from '../src/components/Button'

export default {
  title: 'My stories',
  component: Button,
  decorators: [withDesign]
}

export const myStory = () => <Button>Hello, World!</Button>

myStory.story = {
  name: 'My awesome story',
  parameters: {
    design: {
      type: 'figma',
      url: 'https://www.figma.com/file/LKQ4FJ4bTnCSjedbRpk931/Sample-File'
    }
  }
}
```

`babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

`.storybook/main.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../stories/**/*.stories.js'],
  addons: ['storybook-addon-designs']
};
```

`src/components/Button.vue`:

```
<template>
  <button>
  {{ label }}
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Button',
  props: {
    label: String
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
button {
  background: red;
}
</style>
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Full code here (I'd of done a Sandbox but because it uses Storybook this seems like a better way?): https://github.com/A7DC/storybookvueaddonstest

Comment: This may depend on your setup but try `h => <Button>Hello, World!</Button>`.

Comment: Thanks Estus, unfortunately the error persists when changing it to `export const myStory = h => <Button>Hello, World!</Button>`

Comment: Then the error likely refers to a different place and probably not your own code, otherwise the error would be different. Please, provide the whole error stack. The problem is that the example and probably the entire storybook-addon-designs were made for React, but Vue and React treat JSX differently (createElement or h is used by JSX).

Comment: updated - will add PR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author of `storybook-addon-designs` suggests the following:

You have to replace the `export`

```
const myStory = () => <Button>Hello, World!</Button>
```

You need to change this line (React story) to Vue's one. For example,

```
export const myStory = () => ({
  components: { Button },
  template: '<Button>Hello, World!</Button>'
})
```

Updated answer -

```js
import { withDesign } from "storybook-addon-designs";
import Button from "../src/components/Button";

export default {
  title: "My Stories",
  decorators: [withDesign],
};

export const myStory = () => ({
  components: { Button },
  template: "<Button> Hello, World!</Button >",
});

myStory.story = {
  name: "My awesome story",
  parameters: {
    design: {
      type: "figma",
      url: "https://www.figma.com/file/LKQ4FJ4bTnCSjedbRpk931/Sample-File",
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Oops, you're right! Thank you... I have updated the template but the error still persists unfortunately :(

Comment: try a hard refresh -

Comment: Hey Denis, so I cancelled the Storybook process in terminal, restarted it and refreshed... Still the same error

Comment: looking at the repo and cloned it... 2 minutes

Comment: Thanks Denis, I checked out the PR but still getting the same errors - I assume you're not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211791/discussion-between-denis-tsoi-and-a7dc).